# Unexpected token issue in Java

Tags: java, spring, compiler-errors

I'm currently writing a method inside a service class in spring, but I'm getting unexpected token error message while compiling. I do not see any issue in the code. PFB the code.

```
@Service
public class HelloService{
    @Autowired
    HelloDao helloDao;
    public Long getName(Long id) {
    Person person = helloDao.findName(id);     
        return person.getName();     
    }
}
```

Whenever I create a new method, this error message is appearing irrespective of the class in which I'm creating.
Any idea about this?

Comment: Please indent code for human readability, show us the exact error message, and show us where the error occurs.

Comment: Does `person.getName()` really return a `Long`? That doesn't sound logical.

Comment: Yes.I have just rephrased my code.Even if I have the type as String,it's not working

Answer (score 3):

When I copy/paste that code into my Eclipse on Windows, I see a little square at the end of the two lines inside `getName()`.

The square turns out to be a [Unicode 'LINE SEPARATOR' (U+2028)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm).

They don't belong there. Remove them.

Eclipse actually gives a good error message:

`Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token`

Comment: hi i have problem with catch() in android studio give error message as : error: illegal start of type
      catch(IOError) {
      ^

Comment: @hosein That just looks like bad syntax on your part, but it is out of context, so can't know for sure. If you need help, create a question and include the code you need help with.